# How to convert a web application having no main class from jar to exe using launch4j?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, web-applications, launch4j

I developed a web application using jsp, servlets, oracle database and javascript in eclipse. Now, I am trying to convert its JAR to EXE file using launch4j. Since my application has no main class, while executing EXE it is giving error "no main manifest attribute". What should i do? Help me!

Comment: Please add any applicable code into the question so the community can review it.

Comment: Add a main class which runs the application. The main class will only be used when run by the exe or jar directly. Exe is an 'executable' type. It needs something to run when you click it.

Comment: You're trying to turn a webapp into an exe? Does it contain an embedded server?

Comment: @Fencer04 Thanks for the concern but there is no any code issue. Application is running perfectly in eclipse using tomcat server. When i tried to convert its jar into exe file using launch4j converter, it asks for class having public static void main(){}. But in web applications there is no any such class as it initiates from <welcome-file></welcome-file> inside web.xml which is a simple jsp or html page.

Comment: @PerryMonschau Where can i add main class in a web application. I never saw a web application having main class. If it is possible, guide me. Thanks!

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, it contains tomcat server and oracle database as well which is connected to web application using JDBC.

Comment: @PrasoonGupta No it doesn't. If you had an embedded server, you'd also have a `main()` method, and it definitely doesn't have Oracle embedded in it. You don't really know what you're doing, but if you want to save time you'll forget about the whole `exe` file business. It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Kayaman No, i don't want to save my time. I have a lot of time to learn anything new. It might be possible that i don't know what i am doing but i doesn't mean that i can not do that. If you don't have answer try to mnd your business instead of discouraging other people who wants to give a try. It will save your lots of time.

Comment: @PrasoonGupta You can try all you want. I was just warning you that you're attempting something that is both stupid and impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your web application is the standard 'war' format, with a WEB-INF and everything.  It can have a web.xml, but not necessary.

You need to write an embedded launcher.  Jetty is *great* for this.
You might even be able to use their start.jar, but writing your own embedded launcher is pretty easy.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedding-jetty.html

You write a 'main' function in a launcher class, and set that as your entry point in a runnable jar.  You can do this from eclipse using "Export... / Java / Runnable Jar"